# my graph in ggplot2 contains an "e" character in y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

What does "e" mean in y-axis?

```
ggplot(econdata, aes(x = Country, y = GDP_nom)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', fill = "forest green") +
  ylab("GDP (nominal)")
```

[image: ggplot2 graph example in R language]

Comment: I'm assuming your question will then lead to "how do I my y-axis to show traditional _comma format_ rather than scientific notation?" Simply add `... + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format())`

Comment: @HaydenY. There is something wrong in your computation

Comment: @Chelmy88 Whoops that's what I get for googling math without thinking about what I'm doing. Deleted my comment since your answer says what needs to be said anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` stands for `10^`, it means that 1.5e7 = 1.5*10^7 = 15'000'000. This "e notation" is rather standard and is the programming version of the scientific notation (with 10 power something, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Not that you can define variable using this notation. e.g. for 1 million write `x=1e6`